# Rails - Get the current week's and month's start and end dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am new to ruby on rails and got stuck in dates. I used `Time.now` to get the current time. Now I want to  find out the srart and end dates for the current week and current month. For instance:

If `Time.now` returns me -

```
2012-08-13 15:25:35 +0530
```

Then the start and end dates for the current week are:

```
2012-08-12 - 2012-08-18
```

Then the start and end dates for the current month are:

```
2012--08-01 - 2012-08-31
```

I am implementing the same using the code:

```
Time.now.wday   
 => 1 

Time.now - 1.day
=> 2012-08-12 15:31:44 +0530 

Time.now + 5.day
 => 2012-08-19 15:32:38 +0530
```

and so on.. But I dont find it a convenient way to do this. Iam sure Ruby on Rails does hold a better solution. Can anyone suggest to figure out the same..

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Instead of using Time.now

Use the following code to get your queries solved

```
d = Date.today

d.at_beginning_of_week
#Mon, 13 Aug 2012
d.at_beginning_of_week.strftime
#"2012-08-13"
d.at_beginning_of_week.strftime("%d")
#"13" -> To print the date.
```

Similarly you can find multiple methods in the [Date Class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html)

Comment: This answer has been there for a while, I'm using Rails 5.0.1 in which I can also use `Time.now.at_beginning_of_*`, just thought I'd add it as a comment for the future reader ;)

Comment: @SidOfc don't use Time.now, but `Time.current` instead - it is more timezone aware, that's why

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Date class:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html

The methods beginning_of_* and end_of_* look like exactly what you're after.  For the week, you can even pass in what day you consider the start of the week.