# Ruby on Rails: How to get the current week and loop through it to display its days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time, calendar

[image]

The above picture is what I mean. 
I think the code should be something like:

```
    <% @days_from_this_week.each do |day| %>
        <%= day.name %>
        <!--e.g. Monday-->
        <% day.sessions do |session| %>
            <% @session_categories.each do |category| %>
                <!--categories means the Sesion1/2/3/4 category
                A day's sessionX could be empty, so we have to determine wheather a session matches its cateogry, 
                and then display it in the table
                -->
                <% if session.category == category %>
                    <%= session.content %>
                 <% end %>
            <% end %>
         <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But how to get the `current week`? And how to get the `name of a day`? And to navigate through this calendar, `pre_week` and `next_week` is also needed.

I found`prev_week` and `next_week` method, but it seems like return a certain day after a week, which is not I need.

A possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932091/rails-get-the-current-weeks-and-months-start-and-end-dates), but I don't know how to use it.

UPDATE:
 I found a workable solution, but still looking for better code:

```
  <!--  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
    first=@date.at_beginning_of_week
    last=@date.at_beginning_of_week + 6
    @days= (first..last).to_a-->
    <% @days.each do |day| %>
        <div>
          <%= day %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: Need more information than just this.  What are @days_from_this_week and @session_categories?  How are they related?

Comment: `@days_from_this_week` means the days in the current week, which is what I'm asking `How to get the current week`. `@session_categories` means that a session could belong to different categories( see the table picture, there are session1/2/3/4), so I have to loop through them to determine whether a session matches the category and then display it.

Comment: `session` belongs_to `category`, a `session` has a `date` and a `category` attritube.

Comment: Or put in this way, `@days_from_this_week` means I need to get the `all the days(an array) in the current week`. For example, [2013/8/12..2013/8/18], so I can loop through them to display the sessions of each day

Comment: The last comment made more sense to me :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this in your controller where you're setting the `@days_from_this_week`

```
today = Date.today # Today's date
@days_from_this_week = (today.at_beginning_of_week..today.at_end_of_week).map
```

To show what this does:

```
> (today.at_beginning_of_week..today.at_end_of_week).map.each { |day| day }
> [Mon, 12 Aug 2013, Tue, 13 Aug 2013, Wed, 14 Aug 2013, Thu, 15 Aug 2013, Fri, 16 Aug 2013, Sat, 17 Aug 2013, Sun, 18 Aug 2013]
```

**Update to additional request of querying articles by published on:**

Find all the articles between start date's midnight to next day.

```
start_time = Time.parse(date.to_s)
end_time = 1.day.since(start_time)
Article.where('published_on >= ? and published_on < ?', start_time, end_time)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Another problem: how to show a `day`'s `article`? For example, an article has a `published_on` attribute which is the date it get published. `day.article` doesn't work. Something with group_by?

Comment: @cqcn1991, No, you wouldn't need group by.  Please see the update above for querying articles by date.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844498/rails-3-finding-day-of-week)

A method for the current week would be something like:

```
def current_week
  date = Date.today.beginning_of_week
  return (date..date + 6.days).to_a
end
```

Then when you have the day array, you can use strftime to format the dates

```
day.strftime("%A") # prints weekday name
```

Comment: How can I use the `current_week` to loop through to print the days in it? like [2013/8/12..2013/8/18]